# Probability of Stock Prices

Tags: probability

[image]A model for how the value of a stock changes is that if its present price is x, then after one time period its value will be ax with probability p or bx with probability 1−p(where a >1 gives an increase in value,  and  0< b <1  a  decrease),  independently.   Using  the  data  from  the  table,  we  estimate  that p= 13/23 ≈0.565, a= 1.069 and b= 0.979.

a) If the values of p, a and b held through 2016, what value would you expect Apple’s stock to have on 2/1/16?

b) Continuing to use the values of p, a and b we estimated, and assuming that the number of months between 2015 and the start of 2020 is large, approximate the probability that the Apple’s stock value at the beginning of 2020 would be $257 (or lower).

I tried this several times, and I am getting strange answers. I let a random variable y represent the % increase over a 1-month period, found E(y) and then simply multiplied the stock price by 1+12*E(y). But I am getting a 36% increase which seems completely inconsistent with the rest of the data for the other months. Also not quite sure how to approach b - is it appropriate to use a poisson approximation for b?

Comment: Looks like a homework question!!!!

Comment: Thanks for adding your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Let the starting price be $S$.  If in $12$ months, the stock price increases $k$ and decreases $12-k$ times, the price will be $Sa^kb^{12-k}$.  The expected price is $$S\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}{k}p^k(1-p)^{12-k}a^kb^{12-k}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Can you explain the intuition for that formula please?

Comment: I ran a simulation with that formula for k=0-12 and go the expected price is $925.63. Thats an almost 8-fold increase over 12 months.

Comment: @DanielMotoc I don't understand what you mean by the intuition.    It seems to me to be a straight translation of the problem statement.  Can you tell me what part causes a problem?

Comment: I computed the sum given the values of p, a and b and found the expected price is $925.63. I don't necessarily understand the formula used.

Comment: The number of increases is binomially distributed: $B(12,p)$  The sum is simply the expected value using this distribution.  Numerical computation gives an increase of about $42\%$, so you made some error.

Comment: Yes it was a computational error, that makes sense! So for b), the phrase "assume n is large" makes me think we use a poisson approximation although I am not sure. How should I approach b?

Comment: You can use either the Poisson approximation or the normal approximation to the binomial distribution, as you choose.